# Why does Batman kiss Harley in Suicide Squad?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

In the movie Suicide Squad why does Batman kiss Harley Quinn after rescuing her from the water?

Comment: You sure it's not the other way around?

Comment: He was performing mouth-to-mouth.

Comment: The way it was shot though, the camera angle made Batman look very dominant and in control of an unconscious Harley Quinn. If the intention was to make it look like Batman had been tricked it could have been shot more from the side with Harley on her back and have Harley raise up toward him as Batman pulled away wiping his mouth in disgust or something. I believe it was intended to look like Batman was kissing her.

Comment: That's just because the movie was badly made. Most of the shots were a bit off. To be fair to Affleck, he does manage to pull a kind "For God's sake, Harley" face before the scene ends and it cuts away.

Comment: Because who wouldn't?

Comment: There's spoiler in title buddy...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per Rogue Jedi's explanation, he was performing [mouth-to-mouth resuscitation](http://depts.washington.edu/learncpr/quickcpr.html). I believe that he first checked that she wasn't breathing and/or had an absent pulse. She then turned it into a kiss as per [the trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KissOfLife).

[image: Mouth-to-mouth CPR]

On a side note, **what he did was dumb**. If you don't have a proper protective barrier (And no, [rubber lips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hXX5dD8O9A) would not count), even if trained, it is recommended to do [hands-only CPR](http://cpr.heart.org/AHAECC/CPRAndECC/Programs/HandsOnlyCPR/UCM_473196_Hands-Only-CPR.jsp). Otherwise, you're putting yourself at a high risk for diseases and biting incidents, particularly since vomit and mild psychosis are common side effects of resuscitation. When doing it on a known violent person such as Harley... incredibly bad idea.

And I found a (poor quality) bootleg of the scene. He does check her pulse. His movement is deliberate and fast once he decides to give her mouth-to-mouth, but really, that describes everything Batman does.

Comment: Skipping the mouth to mouth is something that Us and UK do after some random testing they did a while back. It is all published in the "New England Journal of Medicine". In Denmark we still do mouth-to-mouth when trying to revive a person but only if we are fully confidant that we will be able to do it properly. Clear the air ways position the head correct etc, etc.. Most paramedics advisee to skip this and just keep heart compressions. (Coz ppl apparently f**k it up more often than not)

Comment: @Cherubel: Part of it's a safety thing for the person you're giving CPR to (avoiding over-inflating the lungs or accidentally causing them to aspirate vomit), but the majority of it is about the safety of the administrator between diseases you can pick up through the mouth-to-mouth contact to a disturbing number of times when the first reaction of the revived is to try to use the teeth on their rescuer. First Responder kits around here include a device to provide an interface between the mouths to highly reduce the risk.

Comment: Yep we got those awfull devices here too. Plastic, flimsy and way to cumbersome to use in a hurry when you are trying to help a victim. http://www.medicalexpo.com/medical-manufacturer/mouth-to-mouth-mask-2047.html

Comment: When I last did my CPR training a few years ago, the instructor suggested that a handkerchief would do in a pinch, enough to screen out the major contaminants and blunt the force of teeth.

Answer (score 8):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://titanbooks.com/suicide-squad-the-official-movie-novelization-8758/), he wasn't kissing her, he was performing CPR after having determined that she wasn't breathing and that her pulse had stopped.

Interestingly, the scene lasts very slightly longer in the book, making his actions rather more comprehensible.

> *Gripping her firmly, he swam back to the surface. Reaching land, he
>   lay her on her back and administered chest compressions. No response.
>   Only one more thing to try. **It was repulsive, but her only hope.
>   Batman put his mouth to hers, this woman who had just tried to kill
>   him.***
>
> ***He alternated breaths with more chest compressions.***
>
> *Suddenly she wrapped her arms around him, turning CPR into a prolonged
>   kiss. He fought and pulled away.*